# Creating GPT partitions on hard drive

Tags: partitioning, uefi, gpt

I have a UEFI system and am trying to install Windows on a 2nd hard drive (I have linux on the 1st). When I try and install Windows from a bootable USB stick I have created, it does not "see" the 2nd hard drive (in fact it doesn't "see" any internal hard drives including the one with Linux installed). I am reliably informed that the hard drive needs GPT partitioning to be recognised by windows on EFI systems. I am not sure what this means but my real question is: how can I format the hard drive with GPT partitions in order for my Windows 10 bootable USB stick to:
1) recognise the hard drive
2) Install windows 10 on it?

Edit 1: I tried to reformat the HDD in GPT format but this has only made the drive invisible to Linux Nautilus

Comment: Which Linux are you using?

Comment: I'm using Linux Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: If drive was MBR(msdos) then converting to gpt may erase the entire thing. Converting to or from GPT
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html But you also have to boot Windows installer in UEFI mode to install in UEFI mode, just like Ubuntu. If you boot installer in BIOS/CSM/Legacy mode, it will install in BIOS boot mode and only use MBR. Often best to only have one drive connected, but you may have to re-add Ubuntu UEFI entries as when you disconnect a drive UEFI loses its NVRAM boot settings for that drive.

Comment: Is there any way I can recover the drive considering my machine does not recognise it?

Comment: If you're asking that you didn't understand a word of the comment above and probably didn't bother to read the link. To summarize: It's the Windows installer that requires GPT for UEFI mode, not your "machine does not recognise it". Ubuntu has no such requirements but GPT is recommended anyway for obvious reasons. But when dual booting the strictest requirements are the ones you must comply with.

Comment: I don't like your tone MichaelBay. Kindly moderate it. If you read the EDITED version of my original question you will realise that this infers I cannot ACCESS the drive at all. If I cannot access it, then the link is irrelevant. I would ask anyone who posts on this site to keep things helpful and positive, not a vehicle for individual points scoring because they happen to know more about a subject than the questioner.